# How long does it usually take for bug fixes in the Webkit nightly build to hit Chrome/Safari updates?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, nightly-build

How long does it usually take for bug fixes in the Webkit nightly build to hit Chrome/Safari updates?

This is one I have been looking forward to:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22102

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect new webkit features to be 2 generations behind in chrome:

- webkit development
- chromium chrome
- beta
- standard chrome

This cycle can be quite long but usually a new version of chrome gets released 1 month after the previous one. I would count at least 2 versions for a bug to be fixed, so 2 months :)

As for safari, they only update the browser twice to 3 times a year and not in a constant way. Also the updates don't necessarily include a new webkit build but often only security fixes. So you can't really rely on safari for your bug to get fixed but safari 6 coming out this summer with Mac osx lion (probably) will have a pretty new webkit engine. So wait for this summer.